# When sending an XKeyEvent with XSendEvent, the system doesn't respond the first time, then responds on XCloseDisplay

Tags: c++, c++11, x11, xlib

I've got the code:

```
// Send a fake key press event to the window.
XKeyEvent event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, true, XKeysymToKeycode(display, key), modifier);
XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);


// Send a fake key release event to the window.
event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, false, XKeysymToKeycode(display, key), modifier);
XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);
```

Which to my understanding sends a keyboard event to the system, first the press then the release. This works, however the first event does not happen, but when the program ends it sends another event. My theory is that it's delaying the events by one?
Is there some buffer it's being kept in once sent that needs flushing?

So for example I simulate pressing the a key 5 times, it types a 4 times then when XCloseDisplay is called it types the 5th. When putting a delay between each press it's the first that doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance for the help. I can provide more detail on the surrounding code if needed.

**Edit:**added minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// The key code to be sent.
// A full list of available codes can be found in /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
#define KEYCODE1 XK_a

// Function to create a keyboard event
XKeyEvent createKeyEvent(Display *display, Window &win,
                           Window &winRoot, bool press,
                           int keycode, int modifiers)
{
   XKeyEvent event;

   event.display     = display;
   event.window      = win;
   event.root        = winRoot;
   event.subwindow   = None;
   event.time        = CurrentTime;
   event.x           = 1;
   event.y           = 1;
   event.x_root      = 1;
   event.y_root      = 1;
   event.same_screen = True;
   event.keycode     = XKeysymToKeycode(display, keycode);
   event.state       = modifiers;

   if(press)
      event.type = KeyPress;
   else
      event.type = KeyRelease;

   return event;
}

main()
{
   // Obtain the X11 display.
   Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
   if(display == NULL)
      return -1;

   // Get the root window for the current display.
   Window winRoot = XDefaultRootWindow(display);

   usleep(2000000);

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {

      // Find the window which has the current keyboard focus.
      Window winFocus;
      int    revert;
      XGetInputFocus(display, &winFocus, &revert);

      // Send a fake key press event to the window.
      XKeyEvent event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, true, KEYCODE1, 0);
      XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

      printf("keydown\n");

      usleep(1000000);

      // Send a fake key release event to the window.
      event = createKeyEvent(display, winFocus, winRoot, false, KEYCODE1, 0);
      XSendEvent(event.display, event.window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)&event);

      printf("keyup\n");
   }

   usleep(2000000);

   // Done.aaaaa
   XCloseDisplay(display);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. added the example.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what exactly doesn't work here, but try adding `XFlush(display)` after `XSendEvent`.

Comment: @n.m. not sure why it wouldn't compile? It compiles and runs on my machine, so possibly a library issue.(exactly the same code, I copy pasted the entire file). XFlush worked! Thanks :)

Comment: C++ does not allow "implicit int", `main()` is invalid, you must use `int main()`. Perhaps your compiler is horribly outdated.

Comment: I have the same problem. `XFlush` indeed fixes it!